# Why is my idea of the expected value of the number of coin tosses wrong?

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, expected-value

Let's say we want to calculate the expected number of coin tosses until you get heads (including the last throw when you get heads).

The expected number of coin tosses $E$ can be derived for example by recursion:

$E=(1-p)(E+1)+p$ and rearranging yields: $E= \frac{1}{p}$ where $p$ denotes the probability of heads.

What I don't understand is why is it wrong to describe the recursion by:

$E=(1-p)(E+1)+pE$?

I thought that you have probability $(1-p)$ that the number of throws increases by $1$ and probability $p$ that the number of throws remains the same and hence you need the factor $E$.

Why is this reasoning wrong?

*I know that there are already millions of questions/answers which deal with this problem. I am not interested in different solutions but rather in the mistake I made.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your comment, you're confused about what this equation represents.  $E$ is the expected number of tosses until heads comes up.  We toss the coin.  With probability $p$ it shows heads and we stop.  With probability $1-p$, it shows tails.  How many tosses do we need in this case?  Th one we've already made plus the average number of tosses to get heads.  But that's just $E$, so $$E = p+(1-p)(1+E)$$

Another way of looking at is that you always need at least one toss, and with probability $1-p$ you get tails and you're back where you started.

$$E=1+(1-p)E$$

The expectation does not "change over time."  The fact that it doesn't is crucial to the calculation.  The expected number of further tosses we need in the case that tails comes up is exactly the same as the expected number of tosses we needed before we started. That's why we can use $E$ in both places in the equation.

Comment: What I also don't understand is the point that how one can describe the expected value, here $E$, as something that changes over the time. I always had the picture of the expected value in my mind that this is something constant. Do you have a good explanation to fix this in the context in this question?

Comment: The expected value doesn't change over time.  I'll try to add some details to my answer.

Comment: While $E$ certainly doesn't change, the implicit idea here is conditional expectation -- if the first flip is a tail then the conditional expectation is $1+E$, while if the first flip is head, then the conditional expectation is $1$. The formula for $E$ is the appropriate weighted sum of these.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I got it. If I write it down like this: $E= p + (1-p)*(1+\color{red}{\left(p+(1-p)*(1+\left(1+(1-p)*(1+\left(1+....\right) \right) \right)}$. Then I notice that if $E$ exists one can simply replace the recursive part (highlighted in red) by $E$ which yields $E=p+(1-p)(1+E)$. Is this idea correct?

Comment: I don't think you want those consecutive 1's. Red stuff should be an exact copy of RHS. But the basic idea, yes.

Comment: @Ned, you are right, the 1's are wrong. It should look like this:  $E= p + (1-p)*(1+\color{red}{\left(p+(1-p)*(1+\left(p+(1-p)*(1+\left(p+(1-p)*(....))\right) \right) \right)}$.